# how to validate file type and file size in jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

how to validate file type, file size in jquery file upload ?
i am using the following code .

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/VendorReport/UploadFiles',       
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
            .appendTo($('#divUpload'))
            .click(function () {

                var ddlType = $("#ddlType").val();
                if (ddlType == '') {
                    $('#divUpload').empty();

                    ShowNotify('Please select Type...!', 'warning', 2000);
                    return false;
                }
                $('#smp').empty();
                data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));                    
                data.submit();
            });
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        UploadCall(msg.name);
                },
    done: function (e, data) {
        data.context.text('');            
    }
});
```

please help me how to validate file size and file type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the validation options "acceptFileTypes" and "maxFileSize" as seen on the plugin wiki [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options).

Anyway an example:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp4)$/i, //MP4
  maxFileSize: 10000000 //10 MB
});
```